# Is it possible to show folder name before file name in VSCode preview when hovering?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, preview

When I hover on VSCode on the taskbar, it will show the preview of the opening folders

[image: preview on hovering]

Now it's showing file name before folder name. Sometime the file name is too long that it make folder name hidden. Is it possible to make it show folder name before file name so that I can have easier time navigating?

Comment: On Windows, if you hover your mouse over the preview, it will display a tooltip that will give you the full title information. Asides from that, I don't think there is anyway to change this through any kind of settings

Comment: what kind of preview are you talking about? you screenshot shows desktop windows preview. vscode has something called ["preview mode"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_preview-mode). please disambiguate